# Why is the scaling factor in the Robertson-Walker metric squared?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, space-expansion, conventions

Not much to add beyond the title. The Robertson-Walker metric solution to the field equations has the form

$$g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu=-dt^2+a^2(t)\biggl(\frac{dr^2}{1-Kr^2}+r^2(d\theta^2+sin^2\theta \phi^2)\biggr)$$

in which the scaling factor $a(t)$ is squared. I cannot see any reason given for this so far, is this for dimensional reasons or is there a more important reason?

Comment: $a$ is at this point arbitrary, so it doesnt really matter. Redefine $\tilde a=a^2$ if it makes you any happy. The square is useful because it simplifies formulas later on (and also the factor is positive, so that the metric has the correct signature).

Comment: Solved, thank you.

Comment: If $b(t)\equiv a^2(t)$ would be in the metric, then space would scale with a factor of $\sqrt{b(t)}$, which is not as nice to handle (and look at).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to give the answer from @AccidentalFourierTransform

> a  is at this point arbitrary, so it doesnt really matter. Redefine
>   a~=a2 if it makes you any happy. The square is useful because it
>   simplifies formulas later on (and also the factor is positive, so that
>   the metric has the correct signature).

Answer (score 1):

Because $g_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu$ gives you the square of the distance. If the square of the distance increases by $a^2$, then the distance increases by $a$. That's why $a$ is called the scale factor.